# When hosting my application on heroku (specifically when trying to migrate to heroku) I get an error saying module not found

Tags: python, heroku

I am new to software development so please give me input for novices.  I followed the process on the heroku site several times, checked and double checked every step of the process, and can not figure out why I can not migrate to heroku.

This is the error I am getting and I have verified that this module does indeed exist:

```
File "/app/project/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from photo_gallery_aaron import views
  File "/app/photo_gallery_aaron/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import GalleryForm, PhotoForm, CommentForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photo_gallery_aaron.forms'
```

I would be happy to show any code that would be relevant and feedback on how to ask more accurate questions would be greatly appreciated.[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzpsy.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the layout of files under `/app` and under `/app/photo_gallery_aaron`. I suspect that you're missing an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the original post to add a screenshot of my directory